# FCM - Notification appear if send from console but not appear if send from JSON in React Native

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I try use FCM to send notification.

I try 2 methods to send notification,

1. I send notification (FCM) via Firebase Console (Success, push notification appear on top screen)
2. I send notification via https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send. Here my setup :

   ```
   let title = "My Title";
   let msg = "Test Notification";

   let header = {
     headers: {
       'Authorization': 'key=' + serverKey,
       'Content-Type': 'application/json'
     },
   };

   let body = {
     "registration_ids": clientToken,
     "data": {
       'body': msg,
       'title': title,
       'link': '-',
       'click_action': 'OPEN_MAIN_ACTIVITY',
     }
   }
   ```

> **My Question is** The first method work fine (notification appear). But
>   why when i send FCM with the second method, on Android not appear the
>   push notification? Can you find what mistake of the code ?

Comment: Without knowing how your are handling the messages in your app it is hard to say exactly what is happening.  Be aware that there are essentially two types of Messages: `Notification` and `Data`.  Your example above is a `Data` message--it has the `data` payload.  Messages sent from the FCM Console are all `Notification` messages (essentially) they are handled differently on Android devices.

Comment: If i'm not wrong use Firebase Console, that have advance options to add custom data. If i try custom data from console, push notification is still appear correctly. Please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: Adding custom data to the message in the FCM Console creates a `Notification` message with a `data` payload. It is treated as a `Notification` message by the Android device.  A pure `Data` message is treated differently by the Android device.

Comment: Please Read [this article](https://medium.com/@shayan.ta69/how-to-handle-fcm-notification-in-backgrounded-android-applications-29229c4f9975), it is about handling FCM Notifications.